# project in intellij not getting imports from other submodules after generating code via freemarker

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, utf-8, freemarker, maven-multi-module

[image]

this is my project structure for module check-services. check-services has submodules check-services-core,<-- check-services-core-domain,<-- check-services-common-domain. All the code is generated by templates using freemarker.

**Problem 1:** after I generate the code it is not able to import the java files from other modules even though it has their dependency in its pom.
[image]

i tried refreshing maven, invalidating the cache and restarting IDE, adding dependencies manually but nothing worked. any pointers are appreciated.

FREEMARKER :
this is my freemarker config which uses UTF-8 as the default encoding of all the files that are generated. [image]

**Problem 2** : when i try to build the project, it gives me a malformed encoding exception even if i used utf-8 to generate the files.
[image]